# How i can visualize a correlation in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

i have a data frame with 4 variables :

```
library(tidyverse)
y1 = rpois(10,3) 
y2 = rpois(10,5)
y3 = rpois(10,10)
y4 = rpois(10,20)
data = tibble(y1,y2,y3,y4)
```

Now i have a vector of interest say xx:

```
xx  = rpois(10,4)
```

I want to calculate the correlation of vector xx with each column variable and doing so i have :

```
data %>%
  dplyr::summarize(across(.cols = everything(), ~ cor(.x,xx, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")))
```

With result :

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
     y1     y2     y3     y4
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 0.745 -0.600 -0.200 -0.386
```

But how i can use ggplot package in order to visualize these 4  correlation values? (heatmap or colourful scatterplot)
Any help ?

Comment: You mean other than four scatterplots?

Comment: What graph do you want? Bar plot, line chart, heatmap or others?

Comment: @DarrenTsai heatmap not barplot.With any ggplot like package

Comment: @AndreaM yes or one scatterplot with colourful points like bubbles

Comment: See [this page](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-quick-correlation-matrix-heatmap-r-software-and-data-visualization) or [ggcorrplot package](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggcorrplot-visualization-of-a-correlation-matrix-using-ggplot2).

Comment: @DarrenTsai i have seen that but the example that has takes all the columns of the matrix and finds the correlation.My example is different because i have calculated the correlation of each variable with a vector of interest.If for example had to calculate the correlation of y variables in the data wouldn't have asked.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it appears to focus on data analysis or visualization and not a practical programming question as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GGally::ggcorr()`:

```
library(GGally)
data = tibble(data, xx)
ggcorr(data, label = TRUE)
```

[ggcorr heatmap plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z4bh.png)

The package allows for pretty neat pairwise correlation visualizations. Note that this will show the correlations between all of the variables, not just the correlations of each of the 4 variables in `data` with `xx`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a heatmap of correlations using ggplot2

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

y1 = rpois(10,3) 
y2 = rpois(10,5)
y3 = rpois(10,10)
y4 = rpois(10,20)
data = tibble(y1,y2,y3,y4)

xx  = rpois(10,4)


cors <- data %>%
  dplyr::summarize(across(.fns = ~ cor(.x,xx, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  mutate(
    center_x = c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2),
    center_y = "a",
    name = str_c(name, "\n", round(value, 3))
  )

cors %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = center_x, y = center_y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(direction = 1, name = "Correlations\n") +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(reverse = T)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = name)) +
  # theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Correlation with xx", x = "", y = "") +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.key.height = unit(7, "mm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(20, "mm")
  )
```

[image: correlation plot]

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson, see my edit.